# AngularJS forEach stops

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have a Lots object with a collection of lots.
This object is indexed by lotId

```
var lots = {
    800: {
        lotId: 800,
        ...
    },
    801: {
        lotId:801,
        ...
    }
}
```

When I loop through the object with angular.forEach I log the lotId of each lot in the console.

```
angular.forEach(db.lots, function (lot) {
    console.log(lot.lotId);
})
console.log('forEach finished');
```

As we can see, the Lots collection length is 821 and the last lot in the object has lotId 1768

[image]

When this code runs, it prints only until lotId 820:

[image]

So the last log should be 1768, I dont know why it is stopping at lotId 820 (for me this is a big coincidence with Lots length [821]).

Another approach with the native for in loop:

```
for (var lotId in db.lots) {
    if (!db.lots.hasOwnProperty(lotId)) continue;
    console.log(lotId);
}
console.log('forEach finished');
```

Then we have the result I want:

[image]

Things to notice:

- I used the same angular.forEach approach with the same but smaller lots collection (768 of length) and it worked right.
- There were added like 100 lots to the Lots collection and after that the same angular.forEach function I was using stopped working right.
- There are no errors in console.

Any ideas?

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem. Note that objects don't have order like arrays do. Also what does `Object.keys(db.lots).length` return?

Comment: it sounds like it's not printing the lot id, but the object key